Add extra texture coordinates to object for a game
I use Blender to create an object for my game. The game have dynamic textures applied to the object and I need more than one texture coordinate. In the game engine, I can have the normal texture coordinate, and add the additional texture coordinates 2 to 8.
Type.TexCoord
Type.TexCoord1
...
Type.TexCoord8

Can I just copy the UV texture coordinate that I created in blender, in UV mapping, and use it as TexCoord1, TexCoord2, TexCoord3, etc., to TexCoord8?
Currently, I load the mesh and just copy the texture buffer 7 times. But, can I just export the object with 8 texture coordinates?

Hello. Theoretically nowadays in Blender you can have an infinite number of UV maps by using generic attributes on the mesh. I don't really understand the question though, and I feel like it doesn't really concern Blender itself but rather the way texture maps are dealt with in your target engine.

Maybe I didn't explain it well. I create tex coordinates in UV mapping in Blender. If I then export the mesh, there is one set of texture coordinates with the model. I want to have the same tex coordinates copied 7 times and have it also exported with the model in Blender. But maybe my question is silly, and I should do this in my game engine.
